# Proof by boundary operator of the boundary of a closed set has the empty interior

Tags: general-topology

I'm interested in Kuratowski's axioms. I'd like to prove the above proposition using only the boundary operator. Specifically, I can use the following axioms:

Given subsets $A,\ B$ of topological space $X$,
$\partial\varnothing=\varnothing,\ \partial X=\partial(X-A),\ \partial\partial A\subset \partial A,\ B\subset A\implies \partial B\subset A\cup\partial A,\ \partial(A\cup B)\subset\partial A\cup\partial B$ hold.

Assume a set $A$ that satisfies $\partial A\subset A$. How can I prove $\partial A\subset \partial\partial A$ in these axioms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\partial A\subset A$, $X-A\subset X-\partial A$. Then $\partial A=\partial (X-A)\subset (X-\partial A)\cup \partial (X-\partial A)$. Since $\partial A\cap (X-\partial A)=\varnothing$, $\partial A\subset \partial (X-\partial A)= \partial\partial A$.